# How to convert symbols into their respective unicode representation using python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-3.5

I want to convert devanagri script characters such as 'अ' into its unicode representation `\u0905`. 
Earlier in python2.7 I was using `each_character.encode("unicode_escape")` where `each_character` refered to the devanagri script characters.
But lately I have started working on python3 and when I run the above snippet I get the following error?

`expected str instance, bytes found`

Can anybody suggest a way to convert all the characters into their unicode representation. I am working on a devanagri OCR and I need the Unicode representations in order to pass them as ground truths.

Comment: Please post a sample script demonstrating the problem. It should only be a few lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're dealing with bytes object, not string. You should convert the bytes to string using `bytes.decode` method.

```
>>> b = b'\xe0\xa4\x85'
>>> b.decode('utf-8').encode('unicode_escape')
b'\\u0905'
>>> print(b.decode('utf-8').encode('unicode_escape').decode())
\u0905
```

NOTE: You should change `utf-8` depending on which encoding used.

NOTE: If you're iterating bytes object, you should change the code to decode the bytes object first, then iterate; otherwise, decoding will fail or yield wrong result.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an unicode string, like this:

```
text = u'अ'
```

In Python 2, you can use `repr()` to get the escaped representation:

```
>>> repr(u'अ')
"u'\\u0905'"
```

But, in Python 3, non-ASCII characters are not escaped:

```
>>> repr(text)
"'अ'"
```

What you want is to escape non-ASCII characters. You can do I like this:

```
>>> u'अ'.encode('ascii', errors='backslashreplace')
b'\\u0905'
```

The result is a `bytes` string in Python 3 (`str` in Python 2), so if you need an unicode string, you need to decode it, like this:

```
>>> u'अ'.encode('ascii', errors='backslashreplace').decode('ascii')
'\\u0905'
```

The result is an unicode string.

Reference to the Python 3 documentation: [Converting to Bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#converting-to-bytes)